# How much does Power Armour increase your movement?

Tags: movement, armor, dark-heresy-1e

The Power Armour states that it increases Str by 20 and movement by 1, and goes on to say it also increases the size category of the wearer by 1.

The size category chart states hulking gains a +1 base movement.  Does that stack with the listed benefot from the power armour? For a total of +2 to movement.

Comment: I haven't seen the recently released edition of Dark Heresy and have no clue if it matters, just letting you know there are two versions now.  I don't have my 1e Dark Heresy book handy to answer, but I added the system tag and made your title more of a question while I was here.  Welcome to RPG.SE, hope you enjoy your time here!

Answer (score 5):

You get the bonus movement only once.

The DH Corebook is pretty unclear about that but looking at the Deathwatch Corebook page 161 it says explicitly:

> **Giant Among Men:** A Space Marine in power armour is Hulking. This
>   increases his Base Movement by 1 [...]